# How to share JavaScript between Custom Buttons and Visualforce pages?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button

Is there any way we can add Execute Javascript custom page button to Visualforce page and reuse it. I am just checking if any way we can save writing JS code is button again in VF page.

MY Visualforce page in Question is StandardController Page.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have a VF page redirect from the Some JS code Goes here section?please clarify

Comment: Nope its not JS redirection. it executes JS code

Comment: Just a thought you question is probably better titled, "How to share JavaScript between Custom Buttons and Visualforce pages?"

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to store your JavaScript as JS file in a [Static Resource](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm). Then use [REQUIRESCRIPT](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm) (see trick and caviets [here](http://jevonearth.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/using-static-resources-with-salesforce.html)) in the Custom Button script and [INCLUDESCRIPT](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources.htm) in the Visualforce page. This should allow you to share your JavaScript.

Alternatively, depending on your skills and use case, you could also consider writing some shared Apex code either as a shared function between two controllers or a single controller used by both the Custom Button VF page and the other VF page/s in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's an idea: [Allow references to Static Resources on Custom Buttons with OnClick JavaScript](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gHjjAAE).  In it there's a link to this blog post [Using static resources with Salesforce custom Javascript buttons](http://jevonearth.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-static-resources-with-salesforce.html) that outlines a *hack* that would allow you to have a single source of the JavaScript reside in a static resource and refer to it from the custom button using the `REQUIRESCRIPT` function.